# How to write files of the same name to a directory using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to write files of the same name to a directory using Python. Like when downloading the same file from a browser.

I have an existing directory containing the files "aaa.py" and "aaa(1).py".

I would like to add several versions of a file named "aa.py".

The resulting directory should contain:
"aaa.py"
"aaa(1).py"
"aa.py"
"aa(1).py"
"aa(2).py"
etc.

Comment: Maybe try looking if a file `aa` exists, and if it does renaming the moved file to `aa(1)`? Same logic for `aa(2)`, `aa(3)` etc.

Comment: You might find the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module very helpful for your need, especially the function [`Path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) and [`Path.touch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch).